# Liquid-vapour surface tension

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, phase-diagram

In a multi-phase system with a liquid which meets a gas at the free surface, one can define liquid-vapour surface tension $\gamma_{LV}$: is this surface tension a constant when one varies the pressure of the vapour in the system?  My suspicion is that whatever equation one has for the liquid-vapour surface tension would simplify at low pressures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a given temperature, the pressure of the vapour in equilibrium with the liquid  is fixed to be the vapour pressure. The interfacial energy (i.e the  surface tension) depends on the temperature, so in the sense that varying the pressure requires varying the temperature, you are correct.  Unfortunately there is a limit to how low you can make the pressure, because most liquids freeze at low temperature --- the exception being liquid helium.